# How can I refresh an image without repaint flicker?

Tags: html, image

Okay I am going to be outright. I have never touched HTML ever and may be a nuisance. But I understand lua and simple principles of coding. With that said I will get on with my question.

I made a status checker for my minecraft server and used the image to make a desktop gadget I want the flicker to stop when it refreshes. I used other sources and applied them.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>War Server</title>
    <style>
        body{width:560;height:95}
    </style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.onload = function() {
    img = document.getElementById('refreshImage');
    img.src += "?";
    setInterval("img.src=img.src.replace(/\\?[0-9]*/, '?'+Math.floor(Math.random()*9999999+1));", 5000);

}
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img id="refreshImage" src="Status.png" alt="Server Banner" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;border:0;width:560px;height:95" />
</body> <!--I didn't put the actual link for privacy.-->
</html>
```

My Idea:

There probably is a proper way but I'd like to think I could contribute something. I thought I might be able to have a background of the same image  but it updates just before the image. Thus the background would change and then the image would paint and the background would flash(That was what the flicker always was) but it would matter because when it'd had change and flashed the image would've covered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution would not be with html or css it would be with javascript/jquery since you are already using it. You would need to use an if and else statement.

```
if(i==1) { 
    return; //stop the execution of function
}
else {

   //keep on going
}
```

I could provide further advice but you need you clarify your question better. Do you want the picture to flicker until the page is done loading? You used the word update what is it you are waiting for to update?If you are then.

if (document.readyState === "complete") would be your argument so...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>War Server</title>
    <style>
        body{width:560;height:95}
    </style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
img = document.getElementById('refreshImage');

if (document.readyState === "complete") { 
img.src = "Status.png";
return; //stop the execution of function
}

else {
//keep on going
img.src += "?";
setInterval("img.src=img.src.replace(/\\?[0-9]*/,      '?'+Math.floor(Math.random()*9999999+1));", 5000);
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img id="refreshImage" src="Status.png" alt="Server Banner" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;border:0;width:560px;height:95" />
</body> <!--I didn't put the actual link for privacy.-->
</html>
```